# address to string constant

Tags: c

I get an addres of string from assembler into C, and I need to get content of this address.
How to do it? Google gives C++ examples with reinterpret_cast, but it not working in C (I suppose).
I will appreciate if you will note needed libs too, tenx

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

unsigned long const1(void); 

int main()
{ 
    printf("Const: %d\n", const1()); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: show us the code you've tried and where it doesn't work.

Comment: What compiler? What architecture?

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned long const1(void);

int main()
{
 printf("Const: %d\n", const1());
 return 0;
}`

Comment: const1() returns address of string

Comment: architecture: ARM Xscale

Comment: @yons88 for future reference, you can edit your question to provide more info.

Comment: Compiller qemu-arm (I suppose), I'am noob in it, need for university. Really I don't know, what is: pointer or smth else. In asm i get smth like: adr r0, string @ string it is variable that contains string

Comment: You're talking about casting--Chris's answer will do that for you.

Comment: BTW, `reinterpret_cast` is a C++ language construct not a C language construct.  Another point showing they are two different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've already got the address and you know it's a null terminated string, then all you need to do is treat it like a string.

```
printf("%s", (char*)alleged_string_address);
```

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary answer while I wait for your info:

```
   char* foo = (char*)...pointer from assembly...;
    *foo = 'a'; /* write a to the address pointed at by foo */
    foo++;      /* increment the address of foo by 1 */
    *foo = 'b'; /* write b to that address.  foo now contains ab, if it points at RAM.  */
```

This answer is geared toward embedded systems.  If you need a pointer to something like a peripheral register, use volatile to avoid compiler optimizations.

```
   volatile char* foo = (char*)...pointer from assembly...;
    *foo = 'a'; /* write a to the address pointed at by foo */
    foo++;      /* increment the address of foo by 1 */
    *foo = 'b'; /* write b to that address.  foo now contains ab, if it points at RAM.  */
```

Comment: +1 for `volatile`, which was made specifically for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you ***know*** there's a byte with zero in it after the string then try this:

```
char* p = (char*) <your address here>;
// use p for whatever here
```

If there's no zero following the string then the standard string functions in C will fail.